# Query pushdown is not supported because you are using Spark 3.2.1 with a connector designed to support Spark 3.1

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting this warning when I execute my pyspark code. I am writing from S3 to snowflake.
My Snowflake- pyspark packages are

```
net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.13.10,
net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.12:2.9.2-spark_3.1
```

My local pyspark version is

```
Spark version 3.2.1
Hadoop version 3.3.1
```

warning:

```
WARN SnowflakeConnectorUtils$: Query pushdown is not supported because you are using Spark 3.2.1 with a connector designed to support Spark 3.1. Either use the version of Spark supported by the connector or install a version of the connector that supports your version of Spark.
```

Is this the right package or do we have anything other?
My program is working as expected, reading from s3 storing results to snowflake. How to remove this warning?

Comment: It is a warning not an error.

Comment: yes but still i would like to know why am getting this warning

Comment: Read the warning msg

Comment: Yes i would like to know what would be correct package to run? Dont know how to see matching packing for my PYSpark

Answer (score 0):

For Spark 3.2 you need to use Snowflake Spark connector 2.10:

1. For Scala 2.12:

https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:spark-snowflake_2.12

2. For Scala 2.13:

https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:spark-snowflake_2.13